# Marker Interface vs Enums

Tags: java, oop, enums, interface

I am trying model a zoo.

Suppose I have the following structure for areas in the Zoo(omitted some details)

```
public abstract class AnimalHabitat{

   private ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

   public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
      animals.add(animal)
   }
}
```

```
public class Enclosure extends AnimalHabitat{}
public class Aquarium extends AnimalHabitat{}
public class Cage extends AnimalHabitat{}
```

Then I have the following structure for animals

```
public abstract class Animal{}
public class Lion extends Animal{}
public class Zebra extends Animal{}
public class Shark extends Animal{}
public class Starfish extends Animal{}
public class Parrot extends Animal{}
public class Eagle extends Animal{}
```

I want to add an animal to its corresponding appropriate habitat. To simplify code I was thinking to use either a marker interface, such as

```
public interface TerrestrialAnimal{}
public class Lion extends Animal implements TerrestrialAnimal{}
public class Zebra extends Animal implements TerrestrialAnimal{}
```

and then I will be able to do

```
public class Zoo{

   public boolean addAnimal(AnimalHabitat habitat, Animal animal) {
      if (animal instanceOf TerrestrialAnimal && habitat instanceOf Enclosure) {
         habitat.set(animal);
         return true;
      }
      if (animal instanceOf AquaticAnimal && habitat instance of Aquarium) {
          habitat.set(animal);
          return true;
      }
      // So for aerial
   }
}
```

**However** an alternative is to use enums. For example suppose I have

```
public enum AnimalType{
   Terrestrial, Aquatic, Aerial;
   
   //getter
}
```

Then in the Animal abstract class I can define

```
public abstract class Animal{
   private AnimalType type;
   // Initialise in the constructor depending on the animal instance
}
```

And I will do the same in the addAnimal() method in Zoo.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Thanks!

Comment: Use enums where there are only a finite number of things. Animals and habitats have (effectively) an infinite number of things, so aren't well-modelled by enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use enums. You don't need all of those if statements.

Just have the attribute `type` in both `Animal` and `AnimalHabitat` and then compare them.

```
if (animal.getType() == habital.getType()) { // can add to habitat
```

Switch to interfaces if you want to add some methods to the interface specific to the animal type.

Comment: Damn that's so clean! It was actually an assignment, so I couldn't post the question before the deadline(yesterday) :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

### **Enum**

**pros**:

- Easy to scale: You can easily add value
- More coincise: You have one single file to define all AnimalType
- More readable: definitely readable
- More Flexible: You can define method on Enum and you can print AnimalType using enum value
- Comparable: You can do simple compare instead of using instanceof

with enums approach i doesn't find any cons.

### **Interface**

**pros**

- Methods: You can define common methods signatures
- You can use 2 interfaces in same Animal (may an animal have more habitat? Or more types?)
- you can use interface as supertype in collections/class variable

**cons**

- Expensive: definitely expensive, one interface for each type

In your example i prefer Enums because you are using interfaces to define animal types and it can be done easily using Enums. Use interfaces if you need to define common method signatures or you want to use Interfaces as supertype as follow:

`List<TerrestrialAnimal> terrestrialAnimal = new ArrayList<>();` it can contains all terrestiral animal.